# A convex quadratic program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-programming

Let

\begin{align*}
f &:= 4-x-y\\
g &:= x+y+5
\end{align*}

We want to maximize $fg$ subject to $f \ge 0$ and $g \ge 0$.

I tried to solve it using Lagrange multipliers but could not.

Comment: What is $f+g$ ?.

Comment: You have the following convex quadratic program

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathrm x^{\top} (\mathrm 1_2 \mathrm 1_2^{\top}) \, \mathrm x + \mathrm 1_2^{\top} \mathrm x - 20\\ \text{subject to} &  \begin{bmatrix} \,\,\,\,\mathrm 1_2^{\top}\\ -\mathrm 1_2^{\top}\end{bmatrix} \mathrm x \leq \begin{bmatrix} 4\\ 5\end{bmatrix}\end{array}$$ Siong's approach is better, though.

Comment: tanks a lot.  this problem doesn't have a unique solution? why?

Answer (score 2):

Lagrange multiplier is not really needed,

Let $p=x+y$, you want to $$ \max (4-p)(p+5)$$

subject to

$$4-p \geq 0 \iff p\leq 4$$

and

$$p+5 \geq 0 \iff p\geq -5$$

We can notice that the constraints are indeed redundant.

Can you solve $$\max (4-p)(p+5)?$$

Notice that this is just a quadratic problem.

After you solve for $p$. Choose $x=x_0$, you can solve for $y=p-x_0$.

Comment: tank you very much. So it means that this problem doesn't have a unique solution? why?

Comment: the problem is a function of $x+y$, for a particular value of $p$, there are infinitely many solutions $(x,y)$ that satisfy $x+y=p$.